# Task name is getting renamed with Activity using TFS 2018 and Excel

Tags: excel, tfs

I am having backlog in TFS 2018 and I am using default template provided to create the tasks.

The template is having the 'Activity' drop down, while selecting the 'Activity' it is also renaming the Task Title. It is ok if I am adding the task using TFS.

[image: TFS New Task]

Now, I am using the Excel to create the tasks in the user story.

Only problem is whenever I publish the list, it is renaming the Title of the tasks with Activity name.

For example, If I publish the following list, "My Task"  will be renamed with "Requirements- Review" (Value in Activity Column) in TFS board under "My Userstory".

[image: Excel List]

Is there anyway to disable this behavior while adding tasks using the Excel?

Comment: According to your screenshot, why there are two Columns of Title in your excel, one for Title 1 and another for Ttitle2? My side only with Title, what if only use one Title? Did you also get renamed ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PatrickLu-MSFT. Title 1 is for "User story Name" while Title 2 is for "Task Name". As per my understanding both Titles are required as it is creating the Parent Child relationship. In Excel I am selecting Title 1 and clicking on "Add Child" and it is creating Title 2 column. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi John, sorry for the later reply, please see my update answer in below.

Answer (score 1):

> As per my understanding both Titles are required as it is creating the
>   Parent Child relationship. In Excel I am selecting Title 1 and
>   clicking on "Add Child" and it is creating Title 2 column.

Actually we do not use this kind of way to add a nested list of work items( Parent Child relationship)

For example, you should first **convert your flat list to a tree list by adding a tree level**.

[image]

Enter titles for backlog items under Title 1 and for tasks, under Title 2. Also, select the corresponding work item type for each. Here we specify Task.

[image]

Publish your worksheet and  the ID 95 is new created through Excel. In the background, parent-child links are created for each task listed.

[image]

As you can see in web portal, the new create task is list properly and title do not change and activity is also right.

More details please take a look at this official tutorial-- [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT thanks for the reply and explaining it with screenshots. I am able to add tasks on the TFS story board using Excel but I am having the same problem, task name is getting replaced by the activity name. I think this is because of the Template I am using but not sure.

Comment: @John  Sounds wired, never heard this kind of scenario. For this , suggest you could test with  a Team Project which used the build-in scrum template or create a totally new team project and then try to do the same thing in Excel, this will narrow down if it related to template.

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT I will try with the new project having build-in scrum templates as you said. Thanks again for the reply.